# handling main and test without "The declared package com.pkgY does not match the expected package dirX.src.main.java.com.pkgY" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

Every Java project I download has *main* and *test* folders. Both contain *java* and *resources* sub-folders. Some projects even add more levels: for instance *dir1*, *dir2*, *dir3* and etc in the root, where each dirX contains *src* with main and test subfolders. How do I handle them? If I just drop the content of the project root into the default src, Eclipse will attribute classes into *dirX.src.main.java.com.pkgY* obviously resulting in "The declared package *com.pkgY* does not match the expected package *dirX.src.main.java.com.pkgY*" error. Am I supposed to add every *dirX/src/java* directory as a source separately in buildpath, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628686/eclipse-the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package) suggests? What about the corresponding tests? Thanks.

Comment: The answer you found is the right one.

Comment: I think this question is like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781422/junit-package-naming-conflict-in-eclipse-maven

Answer (score 0):

This structure is Maven's `Standard Directory Layout`. In your case, you need to add both src/main/java and src/test/java (right click on java folder and go for use this as source folder) and resources as well to classpath through `configure buildpath` option. Refer this [maven link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed m2e (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases), and if you're doing JavaEE stuff with Eclipse WTP, you should also probably add m2eclipse-wtp (https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/wiki)

Then, you have 2 solutions :

- either right click on each project and Configure > Convert to Maven project
- remove the projects from your workspace and do an "Import as existing maven project"

m2e will take care of configuring Eclipse based on your pom.xml configuration.