# Junit package naming conflict in Eclipse (Maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I want to use the default maven directories for my junit tests, so:

- in Eclipse I created a `test/java` folder.
- I created a junit class in there with a `package com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.test;`

But eclipse is giving me an error.  It wants to change the package name to

```
package test.java.com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.test;
```

Or eclipse wants me to move it to a folder that corresponds to `com/xxx/xxx/tracker/utils/test`

Here is the exact message from eclipse:

> - The declared package "com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.test" does not match the expected package "test.java.com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.test"
> - 2 quick fixes available
> - Move xxxTest.java to 'package com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.test'
> - Change package declaration to 'test.java.com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.test'

I want to keep the junit in the test/java folder to keep it out of the build and follow convention, but it does not make sense to have `test.java` in my package name.

Is there a way to keep the package name the way I want and also have it in the test/java folder?

**EDIT:** Is it because I have projects in my 'src' folder?  For example:

```
src/
   com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.Xxxx.java
   test/
       java/
           com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.XxxxTest.java
```

This project did not start out with Maven.  It was converted by someone else.

**EDIT 2**: More fuel for the fire:

Here is something from my pom.xml (which I did not set up).

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>/home/me/workspace/proj_PARENT/proj_Classes/src</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>/home/me/workspace/proj_PARENT/proj_Classes/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

I do have the eclipse m2e plugin.

Comment: That shouldn't happpen. Can you post eclipse's complain?

Comment: Thanks! Added eclipse message.

Comment: On what tab were you located in the pom.xml editor for the sourceDirectory / testSourceDirectory values. Were you in the "effective pom" tab ?

Comment: nesting the testSource in the sourceDirectory is bound to cause issues... you can configure the build path manually by excluding the src/test from the src folder, but when you update the project configuration using the m2e plugin you should get a "cannot nest" exception.

Comment: Yeah.  I am looking at the effective pom.  I'm on the path now of "doing the right thing" and moving all the source to src/main/java.  I see the nested conflict now.

Comment: Weird.  I was able to fix the problem for the project in question, but I never got the _cannot nest_ exception.  Now I am getting it with another such configured maven project.  _Cannot nest `project/src/test/java` inside `project/src`.  To enable the nesting exclude `test/` from `project/src`_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with you Structure and your classpath. With your descripbed layout the folder src is the root of your sources. But it contains the tests, which should be in a subfolder. In your case you have nested source folder. This MUST lead into compile problems, because a *.java file will be present in two packages. One of the packages is invalid.

```
src/
   com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.Xxxx.java
   test/
       java/
           com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.XxxxTest.java
```

Now you should create two src-folder.

```
src/
   main/
       java/
           com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.Xxxx.java
   test/
       java/
           com.xxx.xxx.tracker.utils.XxxxTest.java
```

Comment: Rewarded as answer for first person to see the nested dir structure issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A maven project following the standard Maven directory layout in eclipse should have the following source folders in its build path (snippet from the .classpath file)

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/> 
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
```

Your eclipse project explorer should look like this :

[image]

If you're using the Eclipse m2e plugin, creating the src/main/java and src/test/java folders on your projects will result in them automatically getting added to the build path.

**Update :**

In your questions update, you're showing that you are nesting your testSourceDirectory in the sourceDirectory.
Most IDEs will warn you against doing that and will most likely lead to issues. 
Eclipse can deal with it by excluding the test part from the source folder, but every time you'll try to update your project config through the m2e plugin, you'll again see the nested exception msg.

If you really want this kind of setup you'll need to configure the build path accordingly (right-click project - Build path - Configure build path).

Comment: I never mess with the classpath in eclipse or by editing the file.  Isn't this setup clashing?  I mean the first classpath will pull in the test cases to my target folder.  That means I really do want to put the source in main/java.
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
 </classpathentry>
 <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
 </classpathentry>

Comment: I'm not saying you should edit the file, I'm saying that whatever maven integration you use (eclipse:eclipse or m2e), this is how your src / test folders should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a new folder `test/java` to your project and configuring it as a source folder in `Project > Properties > Java Build Path`.  Look at the `Source` tab.

Your directory layout should be:

```
project/
-> src/
-> test/
```

Using `.test` as a suffix for test packages might not be necessary and will spare you an import statement when testing `x.y.z.MyClass` in `x.y.z.MyClassTest`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what I did.

- Create new source directories: `src/test/java` and `src/main/java`.
- Take all my current com.xxx.xxx.trackar* packages, select all, right click `Refactor > Move` and I moved them to `src/main/java`
- Create my new junit test in `src/test/java` using a package name w/o the .test suffix.
- Edit the pom.xml to conform to new source directories.
- Right click project `Maven > update Project`.
- `Project > Properties > Java Build Path` see `Source` tab.  Make sure `src/test/java` and `src/main/java` are in there and `src` is not in there.  If it is not correct, go back and update the pom.xml again (and view effective pom)...
- Close and open eclipse again.
- Package name error is gone!!!!!!  Yay!

Thank you all for your help.
PS: I have lost revision control history, but it's because I'm using a legacy system.