# Declaring packages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, new-operator

I'm new to java and eclipse and was wondering if someone could help me.

In my comp class we have a lab each week so in eclipse I created a folder called "compClass" in this file is the "src" folder and in that folder are 3 packages. lab1, lab2, lab3, one for each week we have an assignment. We're currently on assignment 3 so I'm using "lab3" package. In this package I have 2 files, "Test.java" and "MyInteger.java". These files were given to the students and we are supposed to modify them, however that's not my issue.

My issue is on those files I keep getting a compiler error that says: The declared package "" does not match the expected package "lab3" I'm not sure why this is happening as I didn't import anything. I created new java files and copy pasted the code in from a text file. I even tried typing it out by hand and got the same error. I tried dragging and dropping the "Test" and "MyInteger" files (as java files not text files) from a folder on my desktop to the "lab3" package and got the same error. How can I fix this?

P.S. On this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628686/eclipse-the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package/13444301#:~:text=java%20files%20to%20%22package%20path,All%20should%20be%20ok.&text=If%20you%20have%20imported%20an,the%20error%20till%20you%20restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628686/eclipse-the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package/13444301#:%7E:text=java%20files%20to%20%22package%20path,All%20should%20be%20ok.&text=If%20you%20have%20imported%20an,the%20error%20till%20you%20restart).

The top answer said to find the `src/prefix1` directory and right click on it. Then build path and use as source folder. If that is the answer then could someone please help me find the "src" directory I don't even really know what that is or where to find it.

Thank you!

Comment: To put the answer another way, the "package" command has to have a value that exactly corresponds to the folder structure in the "src" tree. You should probably create a separate Eclipse project for each weekly lab.

Answer (score 0):

Every Java project has a project root which can be configured using your IDE. In your case, the root is src/. If your code is inside a subfolder in the root, this folder represents the package your code belongs to, so in this case it's a package of lab3. If you want to not include any package declarations, then either place the code directly inside src or set lab3 as the root.